# PostgreSQL Return Id from t1 where none of the inner join rows from t2 match second condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

t1 (**Properties**)

```
| Id |  Name  |
| -  | ------ |
| 31 | Garage |
| 32 | Depot  |  
| 33 | Store  |
```

t2 (**Addresses**)

```
| Id | Prop_Id | Primary |
| -  | ------- | ------- |
| 1  | 31      | true    |
| 2  | 31      | false   |   
| 3  | 32      | false   |   
| 4  | 32      | false   |
```

I'm trying to retrieve the Id of a Property(t1) that has at least one match in Address(t2) based on **t1.id = t2.prop_id** AND all the matches must have **t2.primary = false**
Based on my table data, I would expect a query to return only the Id **32** from t1.
But all the queries I'm trying return id 32 but 31 as well which is not correct.

```
SELECT t1.Id
FROM properties t1
    INNER JOIN addresses t2 ON t1.Id = t2.Prop_Id
WHERE t2.Is_Primary = false
```

Comment: you in `WHERE` clause use `WHERE t2.Is_Primary = false` so you get all `FALSE` primary

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH test AS (
    SELECT t1.id, bool_or(t2.primary) as is_primary
    FROM properties t1
    INNER JOIN addresses t2 ON t1.id = t2.prop_id
    GROUP BY t1.id
)
SELECT test.id FROM test where is_primary IS FALSE
```

Comment: Hello, did my comment helped you ?

Answer (score 0):

Every time I hear "where at least one..." to me that sounds like a semi-join (exists clause).

Here is an example with your query and dataset above:

```
SELECT t1.Id
FROM
  properties t1
  JOIN addresses t2 ON t1.Id = t2.Prop_Id
WHERE
  t2.Is_Primary = false and
  exists (
    select null
    from addresses a2
    where t1.id = a2.prop_id and a2.is_primary
  )
```

Most of your query is intact, I just added the exists at the bottom.  These are wildly efficient because they look for a match, not all matches.